# Toggling UISwitch sometimes fails to trigger value changed event?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiswitch

I'm using a UISwitch as a main component of my iPhone app, to displays two different streams of content (when the user toggles the switch). I have my switch connected up to call a method on the valueChanged event, and I intermittently experience strange behavior. Over 90% of the time, it works exactly as expected, but occasionally, manually toggling the switch (on both the simulator and my iPhone device) does not fire off the event. The switch physically toggles, but my method is not called.

I have tried this several times in iOS 7 and iOS 8, and I get the same strange behavior. Additionally, I modified the method that is being called to do nothing but display a fading label on the screen that says "value changed", and I get the same exact error (occasionally, the switch will toggle but the label will not display). I've searched for similar issues on stack overflow that people have had with UISwitches, and I've seen some mentions of this problem, but no resolution. Is my best bet to use a custom switch? (Of those, I've checked out KLSwitch and DCRoundSwitch but I would prefer to use Apple's standard UISwitch if possible). Thank you!

Comment: Debug. When it stops working see if the method is called. Is the button target still set. Are there now multiple buttons. Highly unlikely to the an issue with the UISwitch itself.

Comment: I changed to a UISegmentedControl and it works all the time so far. No other code changes

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue. I have imageviews next to my switches indicating the value of the switch with green thick if it is on, or a red X when it is off. Sometimes the when the state of the switch is changed, the image remains in the wrong state. 

The logic to load the image is executed on the Value Changed event of the switches. Today I refactored the code to be called on Primary Action Triggered event. It works so far.